# Incorrect behavior involving critical section in Windows 2000/XP

Tags: winapi, critical-section, c++builder-6

Recently i tried to run an old app (written in Borland C++ Builder 6) on Windows 7 x64 and found that IO-thread was not working. Debugging showed the problem was in error-handling class not leaving critical section (indirectly, via a simple wrapper class), so every message added to log caused two calls of `EnterCriticalSection` but only one call of `LeaveCriticalSection`.

It seems to me that this error should make the class unusable, but it's one of the common classes actively used by original developer, and this particular application always worked fine in Windows 2000/XP. So the question is why this error appeared only in Windows 7?

I've read MSDN articles about critical sections and suggested questions here, the only behavior change noted is undefined acquiring order, which is definitely not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I use C++Builder 6 and my apps work fine with critical sections on Windows 7 64bit.  So your problem has to be due to a bug in the app, not in the API.  If a thread calls `EnterCriticalSection()` and successfully obtains the lock but does not call `LeaveCriticalSection()`, subsequent threads deadlock on their own calls to `EnterCriticalSection()`. So you will have to keep debugging to figure out why the original thread did not call `LeaveCriticalSection()` when it was supposed to.  Every call to `EnterCriticalSection()` must be balanced with a call to `LeaveCriticalSection()`, especially if they are nested.

Comment: I've already found the problem (missing call of `LeaveCriticalSection()`) and fixed it. What i'd like to know is why it works on previous Windows versions, while it obviously shouldn't.

Comment: There is no way it could work. If you do not call `LeaveCriticalSection()`, any other thread trying to get the lock will get deadlocked. This behavior is the same on all versions of Windows.